# set custom height for Sliver children

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

in this below code witch i have problem with that, i''m trying to set custom height for each children of Sliver children, i just learn about this widget on Flutter and i want to fix that, for example:

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: <Widget>[
    SliverFixedExtentList(
      itemExtent: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
        ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxHeight: 50.0,
            minHeight: 50.0
          ),
          child: Text('dddddddddd'),
        ),
        PageView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(color: Colors.green, child: Center(child: Text("Page 1"))),
            Container(color: Colors.red, child: Center(child: Text("Page 2"))),
            Container(color: Colors.indigo, child: Center(child: Text("Page 3"))),
          ],
        ),
      ]),
    ),
  ],
),
```

`Text` widget in that should be have 50.0 size but `itemExtent` avoid to that, and when i set some height for `itemExtent` all children heights inherited from that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the name suggests - `itemExtent:` it gives height to each child.

You can Simply Use `SliverList` and give a specific height to each child.

```
CustomScrollView(
    slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
          ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 50.0, minHeight: 50.0),
            child: Center(child: Text('Child 1')),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 200.0,
            child: PageView(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: Center(child: Text("Page 1"))),
                Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Center(child: Text("Page 2"))),
                Container(
                    color: Colors.indigo,
                    child: Center(child: Text("Page 3"))),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Output:
[image]